# C++ Grid Controls For Desktop Applications

Tags: c++, user-interface, gridview

Is there a c++ library like Extjs that can be used in desktop applications written in c++?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products) which has pretty customizable Grid controls widgets and a lot of examples to learn how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

[wxWidgets](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxgrid.html#wxgrid) has the wxGrid class for displaying grids like spreadsheets use.  It is a cross platform GUI framework.